# php SQL how to keep data and maybe autoincrement instead of replacing record in a field

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

an sql database 'test' having table 'patients' and within table is a field 'prescription' of datatype varchar (200 max length) currently hosts inputted text and numbers.

I'm able to fetch prescription record from the table and display it, then am able to update it through a textbox which happens to overwrite the record in the field 'prescription.

what should I look at doing in order of preserving the record in prescription field, yet write the new one/new prescription? BTW the table row has an 'id' field serving as primary key.

I'm looking at keeping previous prescriptions, whilst writing new ones, and always fetch the most recent one kindof as what it currently does. Later I'll have to look at an option of displaying all available prescriptions for a distinct 'id'.

here is the code that uses the input 'id' by user to fetch table fields:
http://pastebin.com/gNv881kR

The below link shows the code that updates the prescription field:
http://pastebin.com/6sq7ZEtp

Thanks for replying everyone, but what about other patient's prescriptions within same table. as currently table has column 'id', full_name, 'address, 'email', ... 'prescription'. Also I forgot to tell that id is an aplhanumeric value which eg: 232987M which is governmental ID. should I create another table, include current id to use as primary key to search for records using it in new table, and have prescription column and 'id2' which auto increments and copies patient's actual 'id' to assign the prescription and will later fetch all with that 'id' irrispective of the incremented 'id2' ?

Comment: I thought updating is equal to overwriting in normal cases? Use insert to add a new record, you wouldn't need a primary key to add a field as there is no matching involved.

Comment: You need to create a new prescriptions table with a column for the patient id and date of it.  To get the patient data with the latest prescription you just need to join the tables on the patient ID, order by prescription date, then group it by patient ID.  In your update code you would just need to replace the `UPDATE` statement with an `INSERT` one.

Comment: ok, but by insert would I be creating a completely new row with just the 'presscription' field filled-in?

Answer (score 0):

while updating, get max id of the row and add 1 to it , or increment by 1
and then update the details with incremented ID so that it saves as new row

Comment: Thanks for replying Santosh, but what about other patient's prescriptions within same table. as currently table has column 'id', full_name, 'address, 'email', ... 'prescription'

Comment: Thanks Michael - You SOLVED this for me! appreciate your loyalty!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to create a new table with only required fields: 'id' , 'id2'(with auto-increment), 'date' of type date, and 'prescription'

Whenever I update prescription it get actually updated in my current setup in the original table that hosts only one field for prescriptions, yet another copy is saved in the newly created table, with governmental-id and date amended with prescription, enabling me to later fetch results by 'id' field from the new table to display all previous prescriptions.

'id2' is essential as it enables primary-key to take place in order for having each entry unique/distinct from one another.

thanks everyone! and Thanks Michael!
Ian